# Why is Ruby symbolising my hash keys?

Tags: ruby, hash, symbols

I've come across something odd while writing a Ruby module (a set of helper methods for a Sinatra app). I'm declaring a hash as a constant, with keys as strings. Later, when I attempt to retrieve a value, I get nil. On inspecting the hash, I find that the keys have been converted to symbols. What's going on?

Here's a simplified example:

```
module HelperModule

  RANGES = {
    'a' => 1...60,
    'b' => 60...90,
    'c' => 90..999
  }.freeze

  def find_range(key)
    RANGES[key] # Returns nil when key is 'a', 'b' or 'c'
  end

end
```

Inspecting RANGES yields: `{:a=>[1...60], :b=>[60...90], :c=>[90..999]}`.

I can work around it easily enough by converting key `.to_sym`, but I want to understand what's happening here.

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue. I can access the values by string keys normally.

Comment: Thanks for trying. If it was a Rails project, I'd be pointing fingers that way, but this is a very simple app without lots of library code that might do stupid stuff like this. Must be something project-specific though - I can't reproduce it in `irb` either...

Comment: What is in your `Hash.ancestors` (in the same environment, `puts RANGES.class.ancestors.inspect` inside `find_range` should help) ?

Comment: Is it possible you've got some sort of `HashWithIndifferentAccess`? It seems (like Rails) Sinatra does a bit of magic under the hood in some places: https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1083-L1085

Comment: Bingo, @Vasfed - the ancestors are `"[Hash, JSON::Ext::Generator::GeneratorMethods::Hash, Enumerable, Object, PP::ObjectMixin, JSON::Ext::Generator::GeneratorMethods::Object, Kernel, BasicObject]"`, where a plain hash in `irb` has only `"[Hash, Enumerable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]"` looks like one of the JSON libs is getting involved somehow. If you make your comment an answer I'll accept it. That's a useful tool I didn't know about.

Comment: Those that downvoted: care to elaborate? The question is perfectly valid, the answer is useful to others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's something in your environment that alters `Hash`.

Start with looking into `RANGES.class.ancestors`, also look for refinements (those you probably have to grep for `using`)